# How to check for current date, if the column having date and time?

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm

How should I match today's / current date irrespective of the time with column having date as (yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss) eg (2019-04-05 16:00:00.0)
Using Grails GORM findBy method?

Comment: I don't know much about GROM, but if you want to check something like this, can't you use **Like** after converting it to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use between.

```
def today = new Date().clearTime()
def tomorrow = use( TimeCategory ){ today + 1.day }.clearTime()

YourDomain.findByYourDateBetween( today, tomorrow )
```

Probably more suitable for findAllBy.